# one word for someone who can make sense out of numbers or data

Tags: single-word-requests

I have to describe someone with a quality that he can read the story behind the numbers or data given to him. I didn't want to use Analyst.
let me know if there is another word for it

Comment: I think you should clarify what kind of data you are referring to.

Comment: Mathematician? Statistician? Actuary?

Comment: Statistical data... sales mainly

Answer (score 2):

I would describe the person to whom you refer as *numerate*, and having good *numeracy skills*.

You mention a person *who can read the story behind numbers or data*, which is a different ability to that of a *mathematician*.

I was an accountant for most of my main career. I don't think I do any disservice to my colleagues by saying that accountants usually regard themselves as *numerate* as opposed to *mathematical*, in that their strength is in being able to interpret the significance of a set of figures, beyond the figures themselves.

Of course many people with Maths degrees, go on to study accountancy, and have the benefit of being both mathematical and numerate.

Answer (score 0):

[***Statistician***](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/statistician) should fit your requirements.

> n
>
> 1. (Statistics) a person who specializes in or is skilled at statistics
> 2. (Statistics) a person who compiles statistics